# Avoid Telegram's file size limit

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

Telegram bots have a 20MB size limit for files, i was wondering if it was possible to avoid it in python, especially with the pyTelegramBotAPI module.
I found a similar question here on stackoverflow but it wasn't using python.

Answer (score 3):

These file size limits are set for the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files). So I wouldn't recommend using the `pyTelegramBotAPI` module for your purpose. Rather use the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api/bots), which uses the MTProto protocol rather than Bot API endpoints. This allows for maximum file sizes of [2GB](https://telegram.org/blog/profile-videos-people-nearby-and-more?ln=r).

Modules such as [telethon](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/bots.html) or [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/mtproto-vs-botapi) allow to create bots that use MTProto.